# Customer specific validation in JSF

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2.2

I have a business requirement to perform customer specific validations in JSF. Which means, on the same screen same field can be mandatory for one customer and not mandatory for another customer.

I am thinking to implement custom validator in jsf and read the field names from UIComponent so that I can compare them with fields present in external configuration files. These configuration files will have which fields are required to configurable per customer.

Is there any better way to implement this ? Appreciate your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same requirement for multi-customer application: customer on admin site define which fields are mandatory on specified pages (on cardholder site). Flag ("is mandatory" or "is not mandatory") was stored in DB (in configuration table common for all customers). Checking for mandatory field on page was

```
<h:outputLabel for="firstname" value="#{msg.firstname}">
    <h:outputText value=" *" class="required"
        rendered="#{profileAction.isRequired('PF_FIRSTNAME')}" />
</h:outputLabel>
<h:inputText id="firstname" label="#{msg.firstname}"
    value="#{registrationForm.firstName}"
    size="40" maxlength="40" autocomplete="off"
    required="#{profileAction.isRequired('PF_FIRSTNAME')}" />
```

where method for checking was

```
public boolean isRequired(String attributeName) {
    return profiler.isFieldRequired(customerFromSession, attributeName);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This looks more elegant approach.